# Can not start Erlang Application due to bad return error

Tags: erlang

I have a simple erlang application and i am trying to start it to no avail getting a bad return error:

```
> {error,
>     {bad_return,
>         {{mapp,start,[normal,[]]},
>          {'EXIT',
>              {undef,
>                  [{mapp,start,[normal,[]],[]},
>                   {application_master,start_it_old,4,
>                       [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,277}]}]}}}}}
```

**.app**

```
{
    application,mapp,
    [
        {vsn,"1.0.0"},
        {description,"some description"},
        {mod,{mapp,[]}},
        {modules,[mapp,m1]}
    ]   
}.
```

**Folder structure:**

```
-root
  -mapp.app
  -src
     -m1.erl
     -mapp.erl
  -include
      -state.hrl
  -ebin
```

**Application**

```
-module(mapp).
-behaviour(application).
-export([start/2,stop/1]).

start(normal,_Args)->
    Pid=m1:start_link(),
    {ok,Pid}.

stop(State)->ok.
```

**Module**

```
-module(m1).
-include("r.hrl").
-export([start_link/0]).

start_link()->
    Pid=spawn_link(?MODULE,serv,#state{count=2}),
    Pid.
serv(State=#state{count=C})->
    receive 
        {From,MSG} ->From ! {ok,MSG},
                     serv(State#state{count=C=1})
    end.
```

**.hrl**

```
-record(state,{
    count=0
    }).
```

So my `m1` module returns a `Pid`.I comply to the `application:start/2` return type and return a `{ok,Pid}`.
What is wrong here ? I have tried both with `Pid` and `{ok,Pid}` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states that the `mapp:start/2` is `undef`. Seeing that your `mapp.erl` exports it, I suspect that the module `mapp` is not loaded.

How are you running the application? I suspect that you're not using a release tool like `rebar3` or `erlang.mk` because usually the app files are inside src.

Comment: I just run `application:load(mapp)` and `application:start(mapp)`

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian From [erlang's application module](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#load-1) `Notice that the function does not load the Erlang object code.`. You need to either use some erlang tool like `rebar3` or `erlang.mk`, load the code manually with `code:load` or add the code path to the search path with `code:add_path*`

Comment: So i have installed rebar  (and checked it from cmd and git ,works fine) and i run `rebar3 co` and i get the `==>mapp (compile)` but nothing is outputted in the `ebin`

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian the easiest way to start an application with rebar3 is by running `rebar3 new app`, that should bootstrap the application structure. Rebar3 creates the tree structure in `_build`, you should find the `ebin` dir there. You can use `rebar3 shell` to quickly start an erlang shell with your application running for development